# Need to save foreign key manually on belongsTo relationship with withDefault()?

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

it seems that I need to save the original model on the newly generated model in order to save the relation correctly.

I hope the below test case illustrates my problem:

```php
// migrations
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('name');
    $table->timestamps();
});
Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->bigInteger('user_id')->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();
});

//models
class User extends Model
{
    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
    }
}

class Post extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class)
            ->withDefault(['name' => 'Guest User']);
    }
}

//test
public function test_foreign_key()
{
    $post = factory(Post::class)->create();

    $user = $post->user; // created from ->withDefault()
    $user->save();
    $this->assertNotNull($post->user);
    $this->assertNotNull($post->user_id);
}
```

With additional association of the original model the test passes:

```php
public function test_foreign_key_associates()
{
    $post = factory(Post::class)->create();

    $post->user->save();
    $this->assertNotNull($post->user);
    $post->user()->associate($post);
    $this->assertNotNull($post->user_id);
}
```

edit: what I'm doing right now is the following for the `withDefault` relationship:

```php
class Post extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class)
            ->withDefault(function (User $user, Post $post) {
                $user->name = "Guest User";
                $user->save();
                $post->user_id = $user->id;
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: plz post more code, where is the `$user`?

Comment: I edited my question with a more concise example

Comment: if `$post = factory(Post::class)->create();` return post with user_id, `$post->user->save()` will be useless. If not, `$post->user` will be null, and `save()` is added to null.

Comment: It seems my question is not clear enough yet. The `withDefault()` is generating the `$user` in the first test. It's generated through the relationship but doesn't automatically store its id (since there is none) on the `$post` model. I basically just want to know if there's some trick to getting the association automatically (maybe using a closure with `withDefault()` instead?).

Comment: I edited my question to show the workaround I'm using right now.